# How to find a programatically created button by text?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

So my program is generating a bunch of buttons like so:

```
foreach (var subdir in dir.GetDirectories()) { 
    var path = subdir.Name;

    var button = new Button {
        Text = getFlavor(path) + "\t(" + path + ")",
        Width = Width,
        Height = 35,
        Top = y
    };

    button.Click += buttonClick;
    Controls.Add(button);

    if (button.Text.Contains("Kittens") 
        i++;
}
```

I want to try something like this

```
if (i == 1) {
      [Button.ThatContains("Kitten)].Click;
}
```

"ThatContains" is not a real method. How do I get references to buttons I've created programmatically ?

Comment: Store it in a variable (or collection or dictionary), just like any other value.

Comment: I'd really have to create a list of buttons just to get one?

Comment: Do these buttons show up on your form? Are you sure you don't want to add them to your form's control collecion? You can then iterate over all buttons in your form's control collection to find the button you're interested in, and there are even convenient methods to do so.

Comment: Where are you storing your buttons after you create them?

Comment: Sorry, forgot a bit of code. They get added to the control.

Comment: then just  get the button from control and call `PerformClick();`

Comment: _I'd really have to create a list of buttons just to get one?_ You create&manage __one__ list/dictionary and can access __any__ of them at any time.. For only one you simply keep a reference in scope obviously..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `OfType<Button>` to find all buttons in the container control where you've added them(f.e. a `Panel`). Then a liitle bit LINQ power gives you the correct button(s):

```
var kittenButtons = panel.Controls.OfType<Button>()
    .Where(btn => btn.Text.Contains("Kittens"));
foreach(Button btn in kittenButtons)
    btn.PerformClick();
```

If you just want to click the first:

```
Button kittenButton = panel.Controls.OfType<Button>()
    .FirstOrDefault(btn => btn.Text.Contains("Kittens"));
if(kittenButton != null)
    kittenButton.PerformClick();
```

---

For what it's worth, here is also an extension method that returns controls recursively via deferred execution which allows to use only the first found `Buttton` or consume all down the road:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetChildControlsRecursive<T>(this Control root) where T : Control
{
    if (root == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("root");
    var stack = new Stack<Control>();
    stack.Push(root);
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        Control parent = stack.Pop();
        foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
        {
            if (child is T)
                yield return (T)child;
            stack.Push(child);
        }
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Now you can use similar code as above to get for example the first matching button or all:

```
var kittenButtons = this.GetChildControlsRecursive<Button>()
    .Where(b => b.Text.Contains("Kittens"));
// search just until the first button is found
Button firstKittenButton = kittenButtons.FirstOrDefault();
if(firstKittenButton != null) firstKittenButton.PerformClick;
// loop all
foreach(Button btn in kittenButtons)
    btn.PerformClick();
```

Answer (score 2):

Either create a subclass of Button to store the information you want and instantiate that instead or use the [`Tag` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public int ButtonID { get; set; }
}

public class MyApplication
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        int i; // todo: loop stuff
        var button = new MyButton
        {
            Text = getFlavor(path) + "\t(" + path + ")",
            Width = Width,
            Height = 35,
            Top = y,
            ButtonID = i
        };

    }
}
```

Or why not cast the sender parameter of the button click event as a Button and check the text?

```
public class MyApplication
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var b = new Button();
        b.Click += b_Click;
    }

    public void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        switch (b.Text) {
            case "Kittens":
                return;
            default:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As Tim Schmelter pointed out with my answer, this assumes "equals" and not "contains" as the OP suggests. This also requires code-time knowledge of the condition, so you would just have the Click event handler point to a different handler for different cases (or add no handler for default), which probably is against the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

`var button = FirstOrDefault(y => y is Button && y.Text.Contains("Kittens"));`

`if(button != null)`
`button.PerformClick();`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the references, you may need to what you would do with getting references of any other type - store them somewhere, which does not seem to be the case here at all. Normally, you would register your buttons for interaction from a user by attaching them to a `Form`. Assuming you're not doing this by the looks of your sample code, I'm going to recommend storing them into a `Dictionary<string, Button>`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary or you could use a simple recursive loop (in case you are sticking the buttons into different containers).

```
private bool ClickButton(string buttonName, Control control) {
        if (control is Button && control.Text.Contains(buttonName) {
            ((Button)control)PerformClick();
            return true;
        } 

        if (control.HasChildren) {
            foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls) {
                if (ClickButton(buttonName, childControl)) {
                    return true;
                }

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Usage: `ClickButton("Kittens", this);`

Or you could use a dictionary, as some have suggested.

```
private Dictionary<string, Button> DynamicButtons = new Dictionary<string, Button>();

private void ClickDictionaryButton(string buttonName) {
        var matches = DynamicButtons.Where(x => x.Key.Contains(buttonName));
        foreach (var match in matches) {
            match.Value.PerformClick();
        }
}
```

Usage: `ClickDictionaryButton("Kittens", this);`